# How does "migrate" function in PancakeSwap Staking Contract work?

Tags: solidity, etherscan, bsc

I am discovering PancakeSwap Staking contract ! How exactly this below function works ?
Here is address contract https://bscscan.com/address/0x73feaa1ee314f8c655e354234017be2193c9e24e#code

```
// Migrate lp token to another lp contract. Can be called by anyone. We trust that migrator contract is good.

    function migrate(uint256 _pid) public {
        require(address(migrator) != address(0), "migrate: no migrator");
        PoolInfo storage pool = poolInfo[_pid];
        IBEP20 lpToken = pool.lpToken;
        uint256 bal = lpToken.balanceOf(address(this));
        lpToken.safeApprove(address(migrator), bal);
        IBEP20 newLpToken = migrator.migrate(lpToken);
        require(bal == newLpToken.balanceOf(address(this)), "migrate: bad");
        pool.lpToken = newLpToken;
    }
```